# Search Service error Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus : Failed to connect to system manager

Tags: 2016, enterprise-search

In Sharepoint 2016 Application with Search Minrole server i created search service application from CA and after when i open serarch service application i found below error 
I checked in services search-related components running

System Status
Administrative status The search service is not able to connect to the machine that hosts the administration component. Verify that the administration component ' in search application 'Search_Service' is in a good state and try again.

when I run below PowerShell command it shows me

cmdlet Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus at command pipeline position 1
Supply values for the following parameters:
SearchApplication: 1_Search_Service
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus : Failed to connect to system manager. SystemManagerLocations:
**net.tcp://app01/4C229D/AdminComponent1/Management**
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SPEnterpriseSearchStatus